# Can I pass_proxy over https?

Tags: nginx, ssl

Is it possible to have something like this in my **local** nginx.conf?

```
pass_proxy https://mybackend.com:443;
```

**If not**, how do I make my local nginx request and return my remote backend API over SSL?

Comment: Haven't you tried yet? I'm really looking for!

Comment: I tried. Nginx ignores the https part and 443 and still makes requests to http :80.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass : "... As a protocol, “http” or “https” can be specified. ...".